# PHP default DirectoryIndex with a php file started with "." in file name

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-manager

I want to share one of my subdomain to public that anyone can upload and explore any files. I want to it be a simple, so I chose https://github.com/webcdn/File-Explorer project. It is responsive and beautiful. But I need some modifications:

1. Remove authentication -> I did it.
2. Prevent execution of any PHP file (for security reasons) except "explore.php".
   I did it using .htaccess file as below:

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files explore.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

DirectoryIndex explore.php
```

3. The problem is that "File-Explorer" project still shows "explore.php".
   I renamed `explore.php` to `.explore.php` and replaced it in .htaccess, but it doesn't work and the website can't be load.

Comment: Did you restart the webserver?

Comment: @MarkusZeller I use shared hosting

Comment: _'still shows "explore.php"'_ - shows where? Are you talking about what the browser address bar contains, are you talking about the list of files that this script itself generates and outputs - or what exactly?

Comment: @CBroe still shows on "File-Explorer" which I implemented it.

Comment: Something like this should be implemented in the PHP script itself (to be able to suppress arbitrary files). I'm surprised this is not already a feature of the script (but a quick glance over the script itself would seem to suggest that only dot-files can be "hidden", as the default option). Although the "public" is perhaps not the intended audience?? "I renamed `explore.php` to `.explore.php`" - Your server-config might already be blocking dot-files (in the same way it presumably blocks access to `.htaccess`) - this may be the problem?

Comment: @MrWhite Renaming to `.explore.php` can hide it but `DirectoryIndex .explore.php` diesn't work. You are right, it must be managed by the PHP script. I don't know how to do this and author didn't update it. Two ways are here: 1. Hide core PHP file through itself. 2. Change start folder instead root directory (explore.php located in root but file explore starts from <root>/files/  ). Can you see the source on github and help me to edit it, plaese?